# Showing one question on a page in an online quiz app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Please I want to display one question on a page in my quiz app with the next and previous button. I am able to achieve this. What I did is, I added an ID to each question. The initial value for each question ID is 1. So in the next button function, I increase the value of each question by 1. So when the next or previous button is clicked, it will increase or decrease the ID of the question by 1 and then decide which question to show on the page. Also if question ID is 1, the next button should show and hide the previous button. But if ID is greater than 1 or less than total number of question, next and previous button should show. But the new challenge I am facing now is when the question is more than 10, it's displaying two questions on a page and the finish button is not showing. The finish button should show if the current question ID which may be any value is equal to the total number of questions I fetched or want to display. For example, if the current question ID is 20 and total number of questions I want to display is 20, then finish button should show. Else it should show next and previous.

```
This is my code
      <form method="POST" role="form" id="form" action="result.php">
         <?php
          $number_of_question = 10;
          $qryquestions="SELECT * FROM questions WHERE  `course_title`='".$course_title."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
          $qryquestionscheck=$conn->query($qryquestions);
          $i = 1;
          foreach ($qryquestionscheck as $row){
            $question_id = $row['question_id'];
                $questions = $row['questions'];
               $optionA = $row['option_A'];
               $optionB = $row['option_B'];
               $optionC= $row['option_C'];
               $optionD = $row['option_D'];
               $correct_answer = $row['answer'];
               $_SESSION['course_title'] = $course_title;

            $question_rowcount = $qryquestionscheck->num_rows;
            $remainder = $question_rowcount/$number_of_question;
            $_SESSION['question_rowcount'] = $question_rowcount;
            //echo $remainder; die();

         ?>
         <?php if($i==1){?>
          <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: normal; text-align: justify;" class="questions"><b><?php echo "Question" . " " . $counter++; ?></b>&nbsp<?php echo $questions; ?></label><br>
              <div id="quiz-options">
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="A"> <?php echo $optionA; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="B"> <?php echo $optionB; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="C"> <?php echo $optionC; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="D"> <?php echo $optionD; ?>
                </label><br> 
                <input type="hidden" name="correct_answer[]" value="<?php echo $correct_answer; ?>">
                <!-- CHANGED name to same "option[]", value to null and added class unchecked   -->
                <!--<input type="hidden" name="option[]" class="unchecked" value="null">-->              
                <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-default pull-right' type='button' >Next</button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php }elseif($i<$question_rowcount){?>
            <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: normal; text-align: justify;" class="questions"><b><?php echo "Question" . " " . $counter++; ?></b>&nbsp<?php echo $questions; ?></label><br>
              <div id="quiz-options">
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="A"> <?php echo $optionA; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="B"> <?php echo $optionB; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="C"> <?php echo $optionC; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="D"> <?php echo $optionD; ?>
                </label><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="correct_answer[]" value="<?php echo $correct_answer; ?>">
                <!-- CHANGED name to same "option[]", value to null and added class unchecked   -->

                <!--<input type="hidden" name="option[]" class="unchecked" value="null">-->
                <br>                  
                <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-default' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-default pull-right' type='button' >Next</button>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        <?php }elseif(( $remainder < 1 ) || ( $i == $number_of_question && $remainder == 1 ) ){?>
            <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: normal; text-align: justify;" class="questions"><b><?php echo "Question" . " " . $counter++; ?></b>&nbsp<?php echo $questions; ?></label><br>
              <div id="quiz-options">
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="A"> <?php echo $optionA; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="B"> <?php echo $optionB; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="C"> <?php echo $optionC; ?>
                </label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="D"> <?php echo $optionD; ?>
                </label><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="correct_answer[]" value="<?php echo $correct_answer; ?>">
                <!-- CHANGED name to same "option[]", value to null and added class unchecked   -->

                <!--<input type="hidden" name="option[]" class="unchecked" value="null">-->  
                 <br>      
                <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-default' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <input class='btn btn-info pull-right' value="Finish & Submit" name="submit" type='submit'>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <?php }
          /*$option_array = $_POST['option'];
          $unanswered = 0; 
          if (in_array("null", $_POST['option'])){
            $unanswered++;
          }
          $_SESSION['unanswered'] = $unanswered;
          echo $unanswered = $_SESSION['unanswered']; die();*/
        $i++;} ?>

        </form>
This is my script code for the hiding and displaying
   <script>
     var total = parseInt(<?php echo $question_rowcount; ?>);
   $('.cont').addClass('hide');
   count=$('.questions').length;
 $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

 $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
     element=$(this).attr('id');
     $("input[type='submit']").hide();
     last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
     if (total == last){
      $("input[type='submit']").show();
     }
     nex=last + 1;
     $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');

     $('#question' + nex).removeClass('hide');
 });

 $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
     element=$(this).attr('id');
     last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
     pre=last - 1;
     $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');

     $('#question' + pre).removeClass('hide');
 });

</script>
```

Comment: FYI, at anytime I can see the correct answer in your HTML.. Just because input type is hidden, there is still a value set :)

Comment: Alright... I am still working on this. I know it's not suppose to work that way. Further suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Add This jQuery Code:

```
<script>

var total = parseInt(<?php echo $question_rowcount; ?>);
$('.cont').addClass('hide');
count = $('.questions').length;
$('#question' + 1).removeClass('hide');

$(document).on('click', '.next', function () {
    element = $(this).attr('id');
    $("input[type='submit']").hide();
    last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
    if (total == last) {
        $("input[type='submit']").show();
    }
    nex = last + 1;
    $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');

    $('#question' + nex).removeClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('click', '.previous', function () {
    element = $(this).attr('id');
    last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
    pre = last - 1;
    $('#question' + last).addClass('hide');

    $('#question' + pre).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer **@user3102066**. I just updated my code to what you suggested but the challenge is still the same and now when the question is up to 10, the submit button is not showing